# Data from php my form dose note insert to my database and no error is displayed either just a blank page

Tags: php

My form dose not submit the data inserted into my database but it just displays an empty page with no error message and the echo is not executed.

Here is the php code

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))

  {

    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $db_host="localhost";
    $database="logintrial";

    $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);

    mysql_select_db($database,$con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO abonne (N_A,NUMBER,TYP,NO_FTX,ADDRESS,D_R,D_E,lengthone,
     P,lengthtwo,GARDY,A,B,C_F,POLES)
    VALUES
   ('$_POST[N_A]','$_POST[NUMBER]','$_POST[TYP]','$_POST[NO_FTX]','$_POST[ADDRESS]',"
    . "'$_POST[D_R]','$_POST[D_E]','$_POST[lengthone]','$_POST[P]''$_POST[lengthtwo]',"
    . "'$_POST[GARDY]','$_POST[A]''$_POST[B]',$_POST[C_F]','$_POST[POLES]')";
    $a=mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$a)
      {
       echo mysql_error();
      }
   else
      {
        echo "1 record added";
      }

 }
```

Comment: Have you set the right error reporting level? Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: As a reminder, the [*mysql* functions are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), you should use *mysqli* or *PDO* instead. Also, be careful with this code, its wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yes but its not displaying any error and no value has been inserted either @smiggle

Comment: Can you add ```or die(mysql_error())``` after your ```mysql_connect```?

Comment: Yes i already did it

Comment: And? Did it yell any connection error?

Answer (score 0):

You just have 2 syntax error on your SQL query:

```
. "'$_POST[D_R]','$_POST[D_E]','$_POST[lengthone]','$_POST[P]''$_POST[lengthtwo]',"
//                                                          ^^^^
//                                                        error here!
."'$_POST[GARDY]','$_POST[A]''$_POST[B]',$_POST[C_F]','$_POST[POLES]')";
//                        ^^^^
//                   error here also!
```

Just put the comma , between the 2 fields:

```
. "'$_POST[D_R]','$_POST[D_E]','$_POST[lengthone]','$_POST[P]','$_POST[lengthtwo]',"
."'$_POST[GARDY]','$_POST[A]','$_POST[B]',$_POST[C_F]','$_POST[POLES]')";
```

As an advice, when developing, you should set the [correct error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) to spot syntax (and other) errors. To sum add, just add:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);       // If running PHP < 5.4 then E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

in the begging of your script (or even better change the php.ini on the dev machine).

Comment: It still has not inserted the values into the database but thanks anyway for your advice

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output of ```var_dump($sql)```?

Comment: Please can you explain what var_dump($sql) is suppose to archieve @mTorres

Comment: ```var_dump``` is the way to ouput the value of the variable (in this case the $sql variable, my intention is to see the value and check if there are any other non-spotted errors (maybe the $_POST does not have all values?)

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","if you have password to db use it here otherwise leave it empty","logintrial");

 $qry="insert into abonne (N_A,NUMBER,TYP,NO_FTX,ADDRESS,D_R,D_E,lengthone, P,lengthtwo,GARDY,A,B,C_F,POLES)
  values('$_POST[N_A]','$_POST[NUMBER]','$_POST[TYP]','$_POST[NO_FTX]','$_POST[ADD‌​RESS]'," . "'$_POST[D_R]','$_POST[D_E]','$_POST[lengthone]','$_POST[P]''$_POST[lengthtwo]',‌​" . "'$_POST[GARDY]','$_POST[A]''$_POST[B]',$_POST[C_F]','$_POST[POLES]')";

 $res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
```

Comment: Sabastian Wirsiy, is it solved the problem with mysqli?

Comment: No its not inserting into the database@ DRK

Comment: This answer replicates the OP's SQL injection issues.

Comment: So how can i rectify this@halfer